# JS: Сжать изображение

Tags: node.js, изображения, поиск-библиотек, compression

Задача: Сервер получается изоюражение в формате dataURL. Посредством какой библиотеки можно обрезать и сжать изображение?

На клиенте React 

На сервере используется node js

Comment: а на сервере `nodejs`, судя по `javascript` тегу?

Comment: @ThisMan да, конечно)

Comment: можно отправлять сразу обрезанное и сжатое...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопрос как раз заключается в том, как можно обрезать и сжать...

Comment: @FLWRZ4U в вопросе такая формулировка, что создается впечатление о желании сжать именно на сервере...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ суть одна - сжать изображение, как можно это сделать?))))

Comment: @FLWRZ4U какие параметры обрезки и сжатия?

Answer (score 1):

Все описанные манипуляции не сложно сделать при помощи canvas:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let getDataUrl = (url, cb) => loadAndDraw(url, cb);
let crop = (dataUrl, x, y, w, h, cb) => loadAndDraw(dataUrl, cb, -x, -y, w, h);
let resize = (dataUrl, w, h, cb) => loadAndDraw(dataUrl, cb, 0, 0, w, h, true);
let append = dataUrl => document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src="${dataUrl}">`

getDataUrl("https://picsum.photos/300/150", dataUrl => {
  append(dataUrl)
  crop(dataUrl, 85, 10, 130, 130, cropped => {
    append(cropped)
    resize(cropped, 75, 75, append)
  });
});

function loadAndDraw(url, callback, x, y, w, h, resize) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = () => {
    canvas.width = w || img.naturalWidth; 
    canvas.height = h || img.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(img, x||0, y||0, ...(resize?[w,h]:[]));
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
  };
}
```

```css
img {margin-right:5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот библиотека, которая может сжать и изменить размер изображений

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp